# Why the email I send goes into spam?

Tags: email, server, dns, ubuntu-16.04

I use ubuntu 16.04 on my server and recently I've installed postfix MTA on my server following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The problem is the email I send goes into spam, not inbox. Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it? Noted that my domain name isn't into black list. Because few months ago, I did in on another server and emails sent as well *(they went into inbox)*.

Also I send email via command line interface like this:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" <my_email>
```

What should I do now?

---

Also [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/30f1d4af2585882fd0db2b402842c9cc) is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file on the server and this is my DNS records on cloudflare:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a starter you SPF record, does not allow your mail server to send mails on behalf of your domain, it only allows `Zoho's` servers to sent such. If `195.201.0.150` is the IP of your mail server you can allow the sending like this:

```
lamtakam.com TXT v=spf1 ip4:195.201.0.150 include:zoho.com ~all
```

this will allow the IP to send mails on behalf of the domain. Note that instead `ip4:195.201.0.150` you can just write `a`, like this:

```
lamtakam.com TXT v=spf1 a include:zoho.com ~all
```

this allows the `IP` from the `A` record, which is the same `IP`, it just makes one more resolve to get the IP address.

Also Notice that the RR type in my example is `TXT`, this is the proper way to pass `SPF records`, since the `SPF` record type is deprecated. My advice is to create it as a `TXT` record and then just add the new part in your existing `SPF` record, this way you will have `TXT and SPF` records, which is a recommendation from `Bind`, or you can just have the `TXT` one

Comment: I've added that record you said but still it goes into spam `:-(` https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M3M8.png

Comment: Did you wait for the record to propagate before you sent the new mail? I checked the resolution and it looks like you deleted the record, but in my opinion this record is better than the `SPF` you have.

Comment: ok, honestly I give up. one thing dns god, is it possible you connect to my server and take a look at it if I give you the user and pass please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, I will not connect to your server. Just go to `Cloudflare`, add the record again (change the existing `SPF record`), wait for them to propagate and send a mail again. You can check if it is propagated with `dig lamtakam.com TXT`.
Have in mind that the issue may not be related to the `SPF record`, BUT it does not explicitly allow your server to send mails and is telling the receiving server to mark the messages as spam.

Comment: OMG, I just saw that because of a mistake in my answer you created the record wrong. The strange thing is that `Cloudflare` allowed you to do it. In my answer `the domain name was wrong`. I saw it after you created the record and edited the answer, but just now I saw that the record in the screenshot is also wrong. In my opinion this is why it was not working.

Comment: Well do you know what's the correct name as the domain name?

Comment: According to your first screenshot it's `lamtakam.com`, in my answer it was `lamtaCam.com`. Basically the record should be for the `root domain`, not for a `subdomain`. Also do not forget to edit the `SPF record`